# Whilst iterating over a list (I'm using purr:: map) can I get the name of the iteration?

Tags: r, purrr

I read this post, the title made me think I'd found what I'm looking for but I'm not sure I understand it.

I have a list of 9 lists like this:

```
> glimpse(pr_curves_data[1])
List of 1
 $ custom_domain_task_completed_delta:Classes ‘grouped_pr_df’, ‘pr_df’, ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 742358 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ Resample  : chr [1:742358] "Fold1" "Fold1" "Fold1" "Fold1" ...
  ..$ .threshold: num [1:742358] Inf 0.745 0.723 0.702 0.702 ...
  ..$ recall    : num [1:742358] 0 0.000903 0.001807 0.001807 0.001807 ...
  ..$ precision : num [1:742358] NA 1 1 0.667 0.5 ...
  ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "Resample"
  ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
  ..- attr(*, "indices")=List of 5
  .. ..$ : int [1:148902] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. ..$ : int [1:148573] 148902 148903 148904 148905 148906 148907 148908 148909 148910 148911 ...
  .. ..$ : int [1:148504] 297475 297476 297477 297478 297479 297480 297481 297482 297483 297484 ...
  .. ..$ : int [1:148995] 445979 445980 445981 445982 445983 445984 445985 445986 445987 445988 ...
  .. ..$ : int [1:147384] 594974 594975 594976 594977 594978 594979 594980 594981 594982 594983 ...
  ..- attr(*, "group_sizes")= int [1:5] 148902 148573 148504 148995 147384
  ..- attr(*, "biggest_group_size")= int 148995
  ..- attr(*, "labels")='data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ Resample: chr [1:5] "Fold1" "Fold2" "Fold3" "Fold4" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "vars")= chr "Resample"
  .. ..- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE

That was the first one, there are actually 9 all together.
If I double brace it it looks like this:
> glimpse(pr_curves_data[[1]])
Observations: 742,358
Variables: 4
$ Resample   <chr> "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold1", "Fold...
$ .threshold <dbl> Inf, 0.7450786, 0.7234390, 0.7017770, 0.7016966, 0.6987813, 0.6868198, 0.6706202, 0.6632769, 0.6429487, 0.6370495, 0.6352768, 0.6318563, 0.6276031, 0...
$ recall     <dbl> 0.0000000000, 0.0009033424, 0.0018066847, 0.0018066847, 0.0018066847, 0.0027100271, 0.0027100271, 0.0027100271, 0.0027100271, 0.0036133695, 0.0045167...
$ precision  <dbl> NA, 1.0000000, 1.0000000, 0.6666667, 0.5000000, 0.6000000, 0.5000000, 0.4285714, 0.3750000, 0.4444444, 0.5000000, 0.5454545, 0.5833333, 0.6153846, 0....
```

I would liek to iterate over the 9 datasets and write a csv file where the name of the file is, for this first item in the 9, "custom_domain_task_completed_delta.csv".

I'm trying to retrieve this piece, the name of the child list.

Something like:

```
map(pr_curves_data, write.csv(file = [name of the iteration here]))
```

For the first list in the list this would result in a csav called "custom_domain_task_completed_delta.csv"

How can I do that?

Comment: `purrr::imap` or `purrr::iwalk`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I'm reading the documentation for imap with ?imap and I do not know how to get the name back. ```imap(pr_curves_data, function(i) write.csv(x = i, file = paste0([how do I get the name of the iteration for here?], ".csv")))```

Comment: @markus thanks I tried: ```imap(pr_curves_data, function(i) write.csv(x = i, file = paste0(.y, ".csv")))
Error in .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) : unused argument (.y[[i]])```

Comment: More specifically, the syntax might be like `iwalk(pr_curves_data,~write.csv(x = .x,file = .y))`

Comment: From the example in the `imap` docs: "Note that when using the formula shortcut, the first argument is the value, and the second is the position"

Comment: Thanks @Joran that did the trick